# WCF Discovery: Find dynamic endpoint in different subnet

Tags: .net, wcf, discovery, subnet

I'm using dynamic endpoints to find WCF services. So far this works great. However, when the services are in a different subnet, they cannot be found anymore.

I do know the address of the server, but I don't know the port and the precise service name.

Is there a way to use Discovery to find the services?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you need to look at using Managed Discovery as ad-hoc discovery relies on UDP multicast, which won't be routed across subnets:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456791.aspx

Answer (score 0):

We were able to get WCF discovery working across networks. See this [answer](https://serverfault.com/a/619825/11908) for more details.